# how to compare a value with previous value before validate it ( dart / flutter )

Tags: flutter, dart

*I have create a validator to check value format then I want to check a datetime value and compare it if is it after the previous entered value (or great then it) if yes will be validate & save or will show error if is it before the previous datetime (like the example below)*

```
child: TextFormField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                        controller: _controller,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'JJ-MM-AAAA',
                          counterText: '',
                        ),
                        inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9-]')),
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                    ],
                    onSaved: (val) {
                      taskItems.addItem(val);
                    },
                    validator: (val) {
                      if (val!.length < 10) {
                        return 'Entre une date valide';
                      } else
                        return null;
                    },

                  ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      _formKey.currentState!.save();
                      _formKey.currentState?.reset();
                      
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Add'),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, try this:

You first need to parse your **input date** and **previous date** into DateTime() using

```dart
DateTime prevDate = DateTime.parse(date1);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.parse(date2);
```

You can compare your date times using

```dart
if(newDate.isAfter(prevDate)){
  // validate and save value
}
else {
  // show error
}
```

Comment: it's not about comparing datetime it's about compare values entered from user  and validate it before get saving it as list of values

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, especially with saving it as a _list of values_, isn't the value inputted in a date form? If so, compare both the entered value with the previous value

Comment: I'm using provider when i input the first value it will save in list  example : List [value1 , value2, value 3].
i want when i type any value the code compare current value with the previous value if is it less the previous value i print error message if not it will validate
the problem also is when i input the first value because there are no previous value

i hope now its clear